Exact sequence of quasicoherent sheaves
I'm reading the proof of the following proposition

Let $X$ be a scheme. An $\mathscr{O}_X$-module $\mathscr{F}$ is quasi-coherent if and only
for any open affine subscheme $U = \operatorname{Spec} A$ in $X$, the restriction $F|_U$ is of tilde-type;
that is, there is an A-module $M$ and an isomorphism of $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules $F|_U \cong \widetilde{M}$.

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the following property of an open affine $U$ in $X$ : the canonical map
$$\beta_U : \widetilde{\mathscr{F}(U)} \longrightarrow \mathscr{F}|_U$$
is an isomorphism.
The author tries to show that if $D(g_1), D(g_2)$ are distinguished open subsets which covers $U$ and both have the property $\mathcal{P}$, then there is an exact sequence of modules
$$0 \longrightarrow \mathscr{F}(U) \longrightarrow \mathscr{F}(D(g_1)) \oplus \mathscr{F}(D(g_2)) \longrightarrow \mathscr{F}(D(g_1 g_2))$$
Applying $\widetilde{(-)}$ functor to this sequence, which is an exact functor, I guess we have
$$0 \longrightarrow \widetilde{\mathscr{F}(U)} \longrightarrow \widetilde{\mathscr{F}(D(g_1))} \oplus \widetilde{\mathscr{F}(D(g_2))} \longrightarrow \widetilde{\mathscr{F}(D(g_1 g_2))}.$$
But the author uses another sequence
$$0 \longrightarrow \widetilde{\mathscr{F}(U)} \longrightarrow i_{1*}\widetilde{\mathscr{F}(D(g_1))} \oplus i_{2*}\widetilde{\mathscr{F}(D(g_2))} \longrightarrow i_{12*}\widetilde{\mathscr{F}(D(g_1 g_2))},$$
where $i_j : U_j \longrightarrow U$ is the canonical inclusion, and $i_{j*}$ is the pushforward functor for $j=1,2$.
Why should we consider the last sequence, not the above one? and how could we get there from the first exact sequence of modules? Could you give me an explanation?
Edit: I've added the proof I'm reading, it comes from the introduction to schemes by Geir ellingsrud and John christian ottem.
